# Django AJAX modal not showing up

Tags: django, ajax, modal-dialog

I'm trying to display modal form on button click using ajax, but after clicking there is nothing shown on the screen. The screen is turning grey so the modal is triggered, but beside the small grey line at the top o the page there is nothing more show. There are also no errors in console, from my perspective it has to be something with display.

JS function. What is strange is that the hrml_form is shown as unresolved variable, maybe this is the problem?

```
$(function() {

 $('.js-create-book').click(function() {
   $.ajax({
     url: '/patients/create/',
     type: 'get',
     dataType: 'json',
     beforeSend: function () {
       $("#modal-book").modal("show");
     },
     success: function (data) {
       $("#modal-book .modal-content").html(data.html_form);
     }
   });
 });

});
```

forms.py file

```
from django import forms
from .models import Patients


class PatientForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Patients
        fields = ('name', 'surname', 'gender', 'birth_date', 'pesel', 'phone', 'email')
```

views.py

```
def patients_create(request):
    form = PatientForm()
    context = {'form': form}
    html_form = render_to_string('dental/partial_patient_create.html',
                                 context,
                                 request=request)
    return JsonResponse({'html_form': html_form})
```

partial_patient_create.html

```
{% load widget_tweaks %}

<form method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Create a new book</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    {% for field in form %}
      <div class="form-group{% if field.errors %} has-error{% endif %}">
        <label for="{{ field.id_for_label }}">{{ field.label }}</label>
        {% render_field field class="form-control" %}
        {% for error in field.errors %}
          <p class="help-block">{{ error }}</p>
        {% endfor %}
      </div>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Create book</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

patients.html

```
{% extends 'dental/base_layout.html' %} {% load static %}
     {% include "route to the HTML containing the modal" %}
{% block content %}
<div class="page-content p-5" id="content">

    <h1 class="page-header">Patients</h1>

    <p>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary js-create-book">
        <span class="glypicon glypicon-plus"></span>
        New Patient
    </button>
    </p>

    <table id="patients" class="table", style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Surname</th>
            <th>Gender</th>
            <th>Birth Date</th>
            <th>PESEL</th>
            <th>Phone</th>
            <th>E-Mail</th>

        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {% for patient in patient_list %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ patient.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ patient.surname}}</td>
        <td>{{ patient.gender}}</td>
        <td>{{ patient.birth_date}}</td>
        <td>{{ patient.pesel}}</td>
        <td>{{ patient.phone}}</td>
        <td>{{ patient.email}}</td>

    </tr>
        {% empty %}
        <tr>
          <td colspan="7" class="text-center bg-warning">No book</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>

    <div class="modal fade" id="modal-book">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

I would be very grateful for any kind of help.
Thanks

Comment: can you provide whole html file code and jquery code because in your case there is no class of js-create-book of #model-book id in your html file so can your attempt both file clearly

Comment: I cant see an Id "#modal-book" in that template

Comment: I've added the missing html file